# How to stick OBJ vertices to other OBJ

Tags: vertices

i'd like to stick vertices to another object,

make the cylinder take the selected vertices.
i hope the explain clear

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is to have the same vertices on the surface of the cylinder. In that case you have several solutions like delete the cylinder face and fill the faces between the edges and your shape, or use the *Boolean* modifier. Maybe the simplest way, though, is to use the *Knife Project* tool.

- Separate your 2 objects. Select your cutting object, go in *Edit* mode, delete the faces only to keep the edges only.

[image]

- Back to *Object* mode, choose the top view, select the cutting object, shift select your cylinder.

[image]

- Switch to *Edit* mode, go in the *Mesh* menu > *Knife Project*.

[image]

- The shape is now printed on your cylinder. In the *Operator* box (bottom left of your *3D View*) you have the Cut Through option if you want the shape to be cut through the cylinder. Now you may need to clean a bit the topology, depending on your project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will enable snapping, and snapping types can be picked here with the drop-down by the magnet that will toggle snapping.

[image: Snapping toolbar]

You'll want vertex. Remember you can move along specific axes to get it snapping exactly the way you want.

Exactly what you'll want to do is change the snapping type to vertex. Then grab your ring part and move in the y axis, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap it to the rim of the cylinder.

Comment: can you explain mode ?

Comment: but the cylinder don't take the vertices in edit mode ? like third pic !